# Flutter create subCollection in cloud storage

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

Just as you can create subCollection in Firestore, it is posible to create a subChild in Firebase Storage?

In Firestore

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionPath).doc(docID).collection(collectionPath).doc(docID).set({});
```

What about in the storage?

```
FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(childName).child(childID).//what's next? How do I create additional collection to this?
```

Comment: the code you provided will create a folder in the firebase storage with a name "childName", inside the "childName", a childId will be stored, you can create multiple folders by changing the name of "childName" to "childName1" or as you like.

Comment: That means I just have to keep adding .child(), right?

Comment: yeah, if you want to add more sub folder do that.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried give reference name like file path

in my case i used it like

```
String filePath = 'products/images/${_dataRepository.currentUser.uid}.jpg}'

FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName)
```